# Angular automatic scroll

Tags: angularjs, scroll

The question is I have 10 grids and I would like to scroll these div's automatically in angular. what is the best thing I can do,
more probably the data might be dynamic in future. Any suggestions on how to do this would be a great help. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by automatic? You could look at [ng-infinite-scroll](https://github.com/sroze/ngInfiniteScroll) if you want to load endless data as a user scrolls. Your question needs code/clarification/a clear problem statement.

Comment: If you can imagine how the "now trending" section works in facebook that is what I'm trying to do!

Comment: http://joelmukuthu.github.io/angular-snapscroll/#0
see how it goes when the user scrolls I want this kind of behavior automatically without scrolling it.